# is Scrapy-Cluste is production ready?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I am up to setting up my own cluster for scrapping using individual components such as

- Supervisor
- Scrapy
- Kafka for msg
- Celery for queue  and Rebbitmq/redis as broker
- Flask for rest
- Etc

And I'm trying to stitch all this above parts together and make my crawling system.

Came across Scrapy-Cluster at http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

It has very similar specs as

- Zookeeper
- Kafka
- Redis
- Crawler(s) Scrapy
- Kafka Monitor
- Redis Monitor

And by reading document every component seems to be stitch together nicely. It is by istresearch >> http://istresearch.com/blog/2015/4/19/reaching-milestones

The problem is that document seems promising but after searching online could not find anyone using it for real-world applications.

Anyone who is using it for production or anyone who considered it but did not implemented (reason would help) can drop a text.

I know this question is very opinionated but any advice would help.

Thanks

Comment: It still hasn't been released, you are free to contribute but in a professional environment I wouldn't use it just yet. edit: one of the greatest, most informative questions I have ever seen, kudos!

Comment: Thanks @RafaelAlmeida One of the concern i have , component here seems coupled with each other tightly and lack community support for now and everything is not documented yet. but i will admit it seems promising